# Why django is stuck with jQuery 1.4?

Tags: jquery, django, django-admin

I have following problem.
It is quite often that django admin plugins include their own version of jquery and it is not possible to use them together.
For example: django-markitup and django-sortable. Is there any way to get around the issue? Do I need to rewrite plugin(s) to use noConflict?

I understand why developers plug in latest jquery version, but why Django is stuck with jQuery 1.4?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't that big of a problem as django's bundled jquery is namespaced:

> To avoid conflicts with user-supplied scripts or libraries, Django’s
>   jQuery (version 1.4.2) is namespaced as django.jQuery. If you want to
>   use jQuery in your own admin JavaScript without including a second
>   copy, you can use the django.jQuery object on changelist and add/edit
>   views.

The above taken from the [admin documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#jquery).